# Serving an image on django web app

Tags: html, django

I'm trying to serve an image on my Django web app, but it seems to be giving me a broken image link. I put the picture I want to serve in the **static folder** but  the hello.html is in **templates folder** , hoping that would work although it didnt. Here is the **hello.html**

```
{% load static %}
<html>
  <body>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
        <p>Hello</p>
        {% load static %}
        <img src="{% static "filecomparison/Example.jpg" %}" alt="My image"/>
    </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

This is what I see on the website

[image]

I'm new to django and I've been reading guides and watch youtube videos but they dont seem to help me to do what i actually i want, any help is appreciated

Comment: do you need add a preview from your image ??

Comment: in this case you need js : https://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/javascript/#fileinput-examples

Comment: @Tegito123 what do you mean by preview? i literally just want to put a picture i have, its a cool picture that says hello but all i got is that damn icon

Comment: inspect the url from the browser?

Comment: @HemanthSP what's that supposed to mean?

Comment: Put the image in your project app_name/static/ and call it with src="{% static 'image_name' %}"

Comment: @Wariored now I got "Invalid block tag on line 12: 'static'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?" error

Comment: {% load static %} or this {% load staticfiles %} add this in top of your file. Take a look here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

Comment: @Wariored I did, take a look at the code in the question, is that how it should be? Because it still not working

Comment: use {% load staticfiles %} at the top of your file (standard), and once.
And also check if the image is in your app static folder

Comment: @Wariored ya i added the {% load staticfiles % both at the top of the line and second one above <img tag. Previously it doesnt have static folder so i made one but idk if what I made is correct or not. Here is the path for the image i want to show "C:\Users\Public\Documents\PycharmProjects\filecomparison\static\filecomparison\Example.jpg" is it correct or not? Also, when I hover over "filecomparison"  in the <img> tag, it says Attribute filecomparison is not allowed here

Answer (score -1):

When you're using django you have to put images, CSS, JS, etc. in a static files directory. Read up on this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

Make sure you load static files in your HTML with the line `{% load static %}` at the top!

Comment: I edited the code in the question, added your advice but it still doesnt work

Comment: "It still doesn't work" does not help us solve your issue. There are a lot of steps you need to take to get static files working correctly, and there's no way to know which one isn't set up right with your description. Please read the link I sent in its entirety and report back with a specific problem.

Comment: do i need to add anything to urls.py? im confused between development and deployment terms

Comment: "Development" means "DEBUG_MODE" is set to True in settings.py. When this is True, Django handles all of the server stuff and you use `manage.py runserver` to start the server. When you're doing this django is handling finding and serving the static files. When DEBUG_MODE is set to False, Django WILL NOT handle the static files. Your project is "deployed" to some server which handles serving the content; django is just the backend.